# EXE and DLL files compiled with Delphi 10.2 (64 bit) work fine on certain machines and cannot be run on some other machines

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

This problem occurs on some virtual machines under Windows Server 2012 or 2016. I can only run the 32-bit version although it is 64-bit OS.
My DLL supposed to run on ISAPI-DLL mode (therefore called by IIS) also fails (Error 500).
I suspected msolebdsql.dll (SQL Server ODBC driver) to be only 32-bit compatible on these machines, but it seems unlikely.
I've been spending hours on looking for another feature that could be refused by Windows (invalid Windows API call ? There are very few, and it's very common ones). I failed.
Can someone help ?

Comment: Are you sure IIS is 64bits as well as SQL driver?

Comment: Can you check that the application pool running the isapi dll (in IIS) is NOT set to run in 32-bit mode?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. The application pool is not set to 32-bit mode. Also, something I only mentioned in the title: some EXE files cannot be run either. So IIS is not involved, or there are different causes for these failures, which is unlikely. I looked for a dependency check program, but I found only very old programs. I tried Dependency Walker that made a never-ending execution without any result. I also tried to search the windows log, without success: nothing is added to the log when Windows refuses to launch my EXE.

Comment: Running the program using the remote debugger might help in seeing what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have the right to do this. I don't even have the right to have any kind of remote access to my customer's machine. I sent him a very basic EXE file that runs OK. Now I have to add features one by one and check the moment when things get wrong. Very tedious.